# In App Purchase for Cocos2Dx "use of undeclared identifier" in iOS game

Tags: c++, ios, in-app-purchase, cocos2d-x

I'm working on an app source code that for some reason has the In App Purchase code disabled (commented out). The game was built in Cocos 2dx.

Now, I don't know anything about C++, but I researched trying to find an answer to this and I'm stuck.

I'm getting a complier errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "BLACKJACK::BlackJackSetting::submitScore(int)", referenced from:
  MainMenuLayer::onLeaderBoard(cocos2d::CCObject*) in MainMenuLayer.o
  "BLACKJACK::BlackJackSetting::showLeaderboard()", referenced from:
  MainMenuLayer::onLeaderBoard(cocos2d::CCObject*) in MainMenuLayer.o
  "BLACKJACK::BlackJackSetting::isAvailable()", referenced from:
  MainMenuLayer::onLeaderBoard(cocos2d::CCObject*) in MainMenuLayer.o
  "_WebPDecode", referenced from:
  cocos2d::CCImage::_initWithWebpData(void*, int) in CCImageCommonWebp.o
  "BLACKJACK::BlackJackSetting::isCoins1000()", referenced from:
  ShopLayer::onClickPopBuy() in ShopLayer.o
  "BLACKJACK::BlackJackSetting::dispChartboostBanner()", referenced from:
  MainMenuLayer::init() in MainMenuLayer.o
  "BLACKJACK::BlackJackSetting::shared()", referenced from:
  ShopLayer::onClickPopBuy() in ShopLayer.o
  MainMenuLayer::init() in MainMenuLayer.o
  MainMenuLayer::onLeaderBoard(cocos2d::CCObject*) in MainMenuLayer.o
```

Here is the whole block of code:

```
void ShopLayer::onClickPopBuy()  {

   if (g_nProgressBuy != -1) {
     itemPopBuy->setEnabled(false);
     AndroidSocial::shared()->buyFeatureB(m_curPopIdx);
     g_nProgressBuy = -1;
     this->schedule(schedule_selector(ShopLayer::onProcessBuy), 0.5f);
   }

   if ( spPop1->isVisible() ) {
    // Compiler Error: use of undeclared identifier 'BLACKJACK'
    BLACKJACK::BlackJackSetting* bj = BLACKJACK::BlackJackSetting::shared();
      if ( bj->isPaidVersion() ) {
        bj->processIAP("com.prismstudios.BlackjackPaid.coin1000");
      }
      else
      {
        bj->processIAP("com.prismstudios.Blackjackfree.coin1000");
      }

      GameSetting* gameSetting = GameSetting::shared();
      gameSetting->getCoins();

      if ( bj->isCoins1000() ) {
        g_nYourCoin += 1000;
      }

      gameSetting->saveCoins();
     }
   }
```

UPDATED - BlackJackSetting.m file:

```
static void static_setEnable(bool enable){
  NSLog(@"enable GC %d", enable);

  BLACKJACK::BlackJackSetting *gc = BLACKJACK::BlackJackSetting::shared();
  gc->isEnabled = enable;

}

 namespace BLACKJACK
{
  static BlackJackSetting* bjSetting;
  BlackJackSetting::BlackJackSetting()
{

}
  BlackJackSetting::~BlackJackSetting()
{

}

  BlackJackSetting* BlackJackSetting::shared()
{
    if ( !bjSetting )
    {
        bjSetting = new BlackJackSetting();
    }
    return bjSetting;
}

   void BlackJackSetting::alertDialog()
{
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app alertDialog];
}

    void BlackJackSetting::dispChartboostBanner()
{
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app dispChartboostBanner];
}

    void BlackJackSetting::dispChartboostMoreGames()
{
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app dispChartboostMoreGame];
}

    void BlackJackSetting::dispAppLovin()
{
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app dispAppLovin];
}

    bool BlackJackSetting::isPaidVersion()
{
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return [app isPaidVersion];
}

    void BlackJackSetting::showPlayHavenBanner(int nType)
{
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app showPlayHavenBanner:nType];
}


    void BlackJackSetting::onRestore()
{
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app onRestore];
}

    void BlackJackSetting::processIAP(const char* sz)
{
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app processIAP:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:sz]];
}

    bool BlackJackSetting::isCoins1000()
{
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return [app isCoins1000];
}

    bool BlackJackSetting::isCoins2500()
{
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return [app isCoins2500];
}

    bool BlackJackSetting::isCoins6000()
{
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return [app isCoins6000];
}

    bool BlackJackSetting::isCoins14000()
{
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return [app isCoins14000];
}

    bool BlackJackSetting::isCoins30000()
{
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return [app isCoins30000];
}


    bool BlackJackSetting::isAvailable(){
    // Check for presence of GKLocalPlayer API.
    Class gcClass = (NSClassFromString(@"GKLocalPlayer"));

    // The device must be running running iOS 4.1 or later.
    NSString *reqSysVer = @"4.1";
    NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    BOOL osVersionSupported = ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);

    return (gcClass && osVersionSupported);

    return YES;
 }

    void BlackJackSetting::playerLogin(){
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil)
        {
            static_setEnable( true );

            NSLog(@" Authenticate local player complete");

        }
        else
        {
            static_setEnable( false );
            NSLog(@"Authenticate local player Error: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];
   }


void BlackJackSetting::showLeaderboard(){
    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app showLeaderboard];

}

void BlackJackSetting::submitScore(int score){

    AppController* app = (AppController*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSString *category =@"gr.com.goldcion.blackjack.leaderboard";
    if ( [app isPaidVersion] )
    {
        category =@"com.goldcion.blackjack.leaderboard";
    }
    [NSBundle mainBundle];


    NSLog(@"Submitting score for identifier: %@", category);
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category] autorelease];
    scoreReporter.value = score;

    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Submitting score error: %@", [error description]);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Submitting score success");
        }

    }];
   }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your BLACKJACK class or namespace.

Comment: Updated the question with the BlackJackSetting.m

Comment: Why do you need a namespace for keeping the static variable of the class?

Comment: Are you saying I should get rid of the namespace? I don't really know. I didn't write it. I don't really know C++ either.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this code is imported from some other project. BLACKJACK is a namespace which defines the scope of the reference. You need a class for BlackJackSetting (i.e. all the code for it). You likely do not need the namespace (BLACKJACK) at all.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "stop of the reference", but I've imported the `#include "BlackJackSetting.h"` and the errors went away. Now, the error is "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64" when I compile.

Comment: Sorry that was autocorrect. It's the "scope" of the reference. The .h file is only one half. The other part will have blackjack settings code in it.

Comment: Updated the question with the BlackJackSetting.m file

Comment: Have you added it to the project or just to the display above?

Comment: I added it to the project as well and the errors are what are showing now. See the errors that I posted as well.